# Easiest way for removing labels from Rails Admin forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Is there any simple way for removing the labels under forms for New resource in RailsAdmin?

I have "Optional. Length up to 255." under most of the fields although those are mandatory and it's confusing to end users.

I don't have any manually added models, I just use the default config:

```
 config.actions do
    dashboard                    
    index                        
    new 
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app
 end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to get the `fields` method to get rid of the Optional label?

Answer (score 3):

rails_admin [looks at model validations](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/312e53dfd86d7f381ca56b58999faa6be9789eb5/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/base.rb#L176) to determine the help text for each field. Since your fields are being marked `Optional`, I'm guessing they're mandatory by some other means.

You can turn off the help messages using the `help false` statement. If you'd like to do it for all fields on the form, you can use the `fields` method:

```
config.model 'Bug' do
  edit do
    fields do
      help false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

RailsAdmin determines whether a field is optional via the `presence` validation in the model.

To remove the `optional` label, add this line into your model:

```
validates_presence_of :attribute1, :attribute2
```